# finding the edges returned by mincut_value in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

mincut_value in igraph for python returns the number of edges of the cut. Can I find the what edges are actually are returned by this function and print them?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the stable version of igraph (0.5.4 at the moment), but the development version (0.6) supports it. `igraph_mincut` gives you the minimum cut itself in the `cut` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about this, but it seems like [mincut](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc-0.6.5/python/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#mincut) in the python api does not accept source and target arguments (like the c counterpart).

Still, I think you should be able to use [maxflow](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc-0.6.5/python/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#maxflow) to achieve the same thing. It seems they should be similar (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) and [igraph c docs](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch20s01.html#igraph_maxflow)).